# Stripe: How to charge user after subscription already created, when no payment method initially collected

Tags: stripe-payments

I am confused as to whether I should create an entirely new subscription (and lose some of that data in the following subscription) or whether I can use the existing subscription whose status has changed from `trial` to `active`. Do I use payment intents, add a payment method or use some specific subscription method provided? The docs are a meandering novel (that I'm reading) and throwing the question out now as I continue on. Any help appreciated

Comment: is it best to add a payment method first, then charge, or can `stripe.subscriptions.update` accept a new payment method and update the subscription based on the success or failure of that payment method?

Comment: it seems payment intents cannot take in a price id upon creation and so doesn't seem to be the right approach - perhaps just adding a payment method to the customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the customer subscribes to a subscription with trial, a [Setup Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#using-setupintents) will be generated for payment method collection. You may find it under [`pending_setup_intent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent) parameter in Subscription object.

You can follow from Step 5 this guide to complete the payment method collection: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#web-collect-payment-details

Customer will be automatically charged to the saved payment method in the future.

If the subscription doesn't have a trial, a Payment Intent will be generated instead. You can then follow this guide for such case: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements